# Lottery ticket matching numbers system but spamming you lost

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    std::vector<int> winning_numbers {13579,26791,26792,33445,55555,62483,77777,79422,85647,93121};
    
    std::cout <<"Please Enter Your Numbers: ";
    int users_numbers;
    std::cin >> users_numbers;
    
    int size = winning_numbers.size();
    int index = 0;
    bool found = false;
    
    while(index < size && !found) {
        if(users_numbers == winning_numbers[index]) {
            std::cout << "You Won!" << std::endl;
            found = true;
        }
        index++;
    std::cout <<"You Lost" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I am suppose to match the users numbers with the lottery ticket numbers I have in my vector and if they match it says "You Won!" and if you lose it says "You Lost!". The only thing catch is that I need to use a linear search. I finished the program but for some reason when I put "You Lost" it spams it 5 times and not once so I do not know where to put it inside my while loop.

Comment: Your `cout` is inside the `while` loop; move it out

Comment: @VladFeinstein See I did that and when I move it out and use the winning numbers, it says you won and then it also says you lost!

Comment: Your error is one of the reasons I dislike the "brace on the same line" style of formatting.  The error is quite clear if the brace were put on the line below the `while` loop.  [This is an example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d90f831c7afe947).  I know the argument for the "same line brace" style is that it saves space, but I can't tell you the inordinate number of times this either has caused errors like yours, or ends up creating a file with compiler errors, due to a missing brace somewhere.

Comment: You need to remember The Golden Rule Of Computer Programming: your computer always does exactly what you tell it to do instead of what you want it to do. You need to tell your computer exactly what it should do, and only that. Your new version tells your computer to always print "You've lost" after the loop ends, so that's what it does. If you want your computer to do something else, you must tell your computer exactly what it should do.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sorry lol I don't know why every time I add the braces on the same line. It just looks so weirld to me when I put the curly brace on the next line. I need to remember that, thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple mistake. While the indentation would make you think everything is fine, your matching curly bracket is in the incorrect location for the while loop. Currently, it spams the "You Lost" at the completion of every index that it scans because it is being told to. I would suggest the following changes:

```
while(index < size && !found) {
    if(users_numbers == winning_numbers[index]) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
    index++;
}
if (found)
    std::cout << "You Won!" << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "You Lost" << std::endl;
```

Now, the code will check every item in the list until it finds the matching pair. Once that occurs, it will stop scanning the list and output "You Won!" If no matching pairs are found by the end, the "You Lost" message will display.

Comment: Though I realize now after having posted this, you don't need the break since you take that into account in the while statement.

Comment: I am just curious, why is the if and else statement outside of the while loop? Shouldn't it be inside.

Comment: If you wanted to, you could place the "You Won!" inside the while loop as you did originally. But you need to check that boolean value somewhere so that the program can determine if it needs to output the "You Lost" message. Therefore, that message should be outside of the loop so that we know every possible chance of a match has been exhausted.

Comment: As an alternative, if you really want it inside of the while loop, you could add the following code inside the loop and after the first if block: (`if(!found && index == size - 1) std::cout << "You Lost" << std::endl;`) This should ensure we reached the end of the list and no matches were found.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting `std::cout << "You Lost" << std::endl;` inside the while-loop, so it is repeated each time the loop iterates.
You should put it outside the while-loop, for example like this: `ìf(!found) std::cout << "You lost" << std::endl;`